# how to subtract and compare the value from multiple datagridviews?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

**compare 2 datagridviews's values and the values will be datetime.**

**STEP 1**

I used if statement to match the value in **column(ID)** and **column(daterange)**, if it's correct, I'll past them to a new column. [I get the correct result]

but when

**STEP 2**

I try to add-in more conditions to compare the **columns(time)** [my expected  results all are incorrect ("No-in")]

Anyone can help me or share opinion on this?

```
Dim storageEarlyin As String
Dim storagelatein As String
'Dim storatimetemp As DateTime = "12:00:00 PM"
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim count As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

    For i = 0 To (count - 1)
        Dim clockeddate As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value).ToShortDateString
        Dim userid As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim count2 As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows.Count
        Dim clockedtime As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value).ToShortTimeString

        For i2 = 0 To (count2 - 1)

            Dim daterange As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(1).Value).ToShortDateString
            Dim userid2 As String = DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            Dim workstart As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(5).Value).ToShortTimeString
            Dim ClockAvailableStart As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(3).Value).ToShortTimeString
            Dim workend As String = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(6).Value).ToShortTimeString

            If userid = userid2 And clockeddate = daterange Then
                If clockedtime <= workstart And clockedtime >= ClockAvailableStart Then
                    storageEarlyin = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToShortTimeString
                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(7).Value = storageEarlyin
                Else
                    storageEarlyin = "No-in"
                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(7).Value = storageEarlyin
                End If

                If clockedtime > workstart And clockedtime < workend Then
                    storagelatein = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToShortTimeString
                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(8).Value = storagelatein
                Else
                    storagelatein = "No-in"
                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(8).Value = storagelatein
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: show sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

You create a variable `clockedtime ,workstart ClockAvailableStar`t  are `string` type, So the if condition (`clockedtime <= workstart And clockedtime >= ClockAvailableStart`) not working properly so change the data type is datetime like

```
 Dim clockedtime As DateTime= 
 Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value).ToShortTimeString

 Dim workstart As DateTime= 
 Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(5).Value).ToShortTimeString

 Dim ClockAvailableStart As DateTime= 
 Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView2.Rows(i2).Cells(3).Value).ToShortTimeString
```

After that its working properly

Comment: i got do some edit on my question, thx sir i will try it now!

Comment: As the correction you posted, i had tried look trough mostly correct! but i have to include all the time frame only know the exactly results correct ornot!! anyway thx first!! SATSON

Comment: `all the time frame only` means i can't understand clearly. after changing data type its not working ah?

Comment: just works find thx man! time frame means i still got rest time(s), workend, ealrly out, lateout, and clockend.